# Android - Whiter tab icons when selected

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

I have an appCompactActivity with icon tabs. The tabs are part of a TabLayout. I want that the selected tab icon will get whiter.

Edit:

I want to do it programmatically

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to create a selector for your icon on yout tablayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_pressed"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_selected"
      android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_normal" />
```

Save this xml in your drawable folder and use it with R.drawable.myicon

Comment: Also you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828951/tab-with-icon-using-tablayout-in-android-design-library

Comment: Is there a way to do that programmatically?

Comment: There is another way, I suppose that in your onTabSelected method, you might have to add your icon when is selected and in your onTabUnselected your icon when is unselected but as far I read is better to use a drawable.

Comment: the icons seems to be a little grayer then the original drawable. A selector won't work here because the icon is fully white and i can't change him to a whiter one.